# Moving to CentOS 7 from UBUNTU dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, centos, dual-boot, grub

I currently have a Dual boot OS (**Ubuntu 18.04** and **Windows 10**). Due to the software I have to work on, I need to migrate to **CentOS 7**.

Is there any guide to migrate without corrupting the Windows 10 installation? In other words,replacing ubuntu without destroying the boot files for windows? I know it is the **GRUB** that I am concerned about, and since now I am not upgrading UBUNTU but installing new distro, I have no idea if this would maintain the GRUB replace it safely. I also can not install CentOS side by side due to storage limit.

Comment: I assume you are using UEFI?

Comment: @jsbillings yes that's correct